# How to get the content moderation entity related to node entity in drupal 8.2.x?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

from a content moderation entity, i know how to get the associated node:

```
 if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'content_moderation_state' ) {
     $article_id=$entity->get('content_entity_id')->getString();
     $article = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($article_id);
 }
```

What i need to do is the reverse.
Being able from hook_form_alter, to get the content moderation entity related to the node:

```
 function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id='node_article_edit_form')
  {
    $node=$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    //$node->get_content_moderation_entity??

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it with entityQuery

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
 if ($form_id='node_article_edit_form')
  {      
    $article=$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    //get the associated content moderation entity
    $id = Drupal::entityQuery('content_moderation_state')
       ->condition('content_entity_id', $article->id())
        ->execute();

    $stateEntities = Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getStorage('content_moderation_state')
        ->loadMultiple($id);
    $stateEntity=array_values($stateEntities)[0];
    $moderation_state = $stateEntity->get('moderation_state')->getString();
   }
 }
```